# undefined method `protect_against_forgery?' for #<#<Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am struggeling with, what I think is a simple issue. I am creating a signup form where you create and account and a user (an account can have many users). However when loading the new.html.erb view I receive the following error:

```
undefined method `protect_against_forgery?' for #<#<Class:0x00>
```

The account_controller.rb looks like this:

```
class AccountController < ApplicationController

    def new 
        @account = Account.new
        @account.users.build
    end

end
```

And the view:

```
    <h2>Create account</h2>

  <%= form_with model: @account, url: :new_account do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>

      <h4><%= f.label :name, 'Account Name' %></h4>
      <%= f.text_field :name, :required => true, :placeholder => 'Your account name' %>


      <%= f.fields_for :users do |user_form| %>
          <h4><%= user_form.label :name %></h4>
          <%= user_form.text_field :name, :autofocus => true, :required => true, :placeholder => 'Your name' %>


          <h4><%= user_form.label :email %></h4>
          <%= user_form.email_field :email, :required => true, :placeholder => 'Your email' %>


          <h4><%= user_form.label :password, :required => true %></h4>
          <%= user_form.password_field :password, :required => true, :placeholder => 'Enter a 8 character password'%>

          <h4><%= user_form.label :password_confirmation, :required => true %></h4>
          <%= user_form.password_field :password_confirmation, :required => true, :placeholder => 'Confirm password' %>

          <div class="remember-me">
              <%= f.check_box :terms_and_conditions %>
              <%= link_to 'Accept terms and conditions', 'todo', :target => '_blank' %>
          </div>
      <% end %>

      <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Create account" />
  <% end %>
```

I haven't been able to find any others with the exact same issue (closest one was an issue with mailing templates, but couldn't find the connection).

Hope someone can guide me in the right direction since I am staring blind on this.

Comment: I think this is your issue https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4003#issuecomment-271170592
If not, you could post the entire trace (including framework)

Comment: What does your ApplicationController look like?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error with help of @vise. I somehow had created the project as an API project, and in my application_controller.rb it inherited from API instead of Base.

I changed this and added:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

And it worked. Thanks for the help!